# objective-c difference between x.y and [x y]?

Tags: objective-c

An example that made me ask is:

Xcode tells me to

> // Get the new view controller using [segue
>   destinationViewController].

but i did it like this

```
destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
```

Im just starting to learn objective-c, i'v only ever wrote c++. Could someone elaborate on the [ ] and the difference between `segue.destinationViewController` and `[segue destinationViewController]` and when you should use one or the other? (I don't know what terminology to search)

destinationViewController just holds the pointer to a view controller and is not a method right? This is whats confusing my i thought [x y] syntax is for calling methods so why does xcode tell me to do this?

Comment: the terminology to search for can be something like "method call vs. dot notation". They're equivalent apart from the fact that `[obj method]` can't be assigned to (whereas `obj.prop` can), and the dot notation triggers a hard error if the compiler can't find the method/property declaration, while unknown method calls only result in a warning (and a runtime "unrecognized selector" exception).

Comment: I don't understand how destinationViewController can be called using the method call syntax when it is declared as a property id
`@property (nonatomic, readonly) id destinationViewController;`

Comment: Read a beginner Objective-C tutorial, then. My comment above says "they're equivalent [...]" for a reason.